# What is EOM meaning in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

```
/bin/cat <<EOM >$FILE
```

What is EOM (and EOF) meaning ,i try to find out with google and it cant give me answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](https://i.imgur.com/3ppJhiE.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time. You also have a preview pane right below the editor so you can see how changes look like before you publish them.

Comment: Search for "here documents".

Comment: Short answer: it doesn't mean anything the shell cares about. It's just a marker you'll type later. You could type `PINKUNICORNS` and it would still work.

Comment: My suggestion is: ``EOM`` = End of Message and ``EOF`` = End of File. As @ÁlvaroGonzález stated, they are just marker.